# Is firebase OTP is free or there is a usage fee?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am planing to use firebase OTP in my project but not sure is it free or not. Seems like it is free

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about product or service pricing are off topic as explained in [Are questions on prices or support of developer services on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274576) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Edit: as per their new policy only 10 sms/day is free

Per the Firebase pricing page, you have free **10K successful verifications every month.** In a month if you cross more than 10K verifications, then you might be charged.

> Prices are per successful verification.
>
> On the Blaze plan, Phone Authentication provides a perpetual free tier. The first 10K verifications are provided for free each month. You are only charged on usage past this free allotment.
>
> All other Firebase Auth features are free to use on all plans.

[image]

Reference : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: @Arun Kumar does that mean I am getting charged only when user receives sms or authentication considered everytime firebase wants to validate your session?

Comment: They removed the "all other features are free" part 

Comment: Appreciate for what they done. But It is disappointing they changed from 10K/month to just 10/day of free authentication without notice.

Answer (score 4):

To check the prices of Firebase products, please check the link below:

https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

According to the link:

> Free Products:
>
> Authentication (except Phone Auth), Analytics, Predictions, App Indexing, Dynamic Links, Invites, Remote Config, Cloud Messaging (FCM), Performance Monitoring, Crash Reporting, and Crashlytics.

Comment: so  Phone auth is not free is it ? I think we need to do the phone auth  for the Fire base OTP  am I correct ?

Comment: yes thats correct, OTP is related to phone auth. If you check the link, then scroll down there is price for phone auth

Answer (score 1):

Prices are per successful verification.

On the Blaze plan, Phone Authentication provides a perpetual free tier. The first 10K verifications for both instances (USA, Canada, and India and All other countries) are provided for free each month. You are only charged on usage past this free allotment.

All other Firebase Auth features are free to use on all plans

Comment: Hi Yenui 
what is charges after 10K  or after day limit ?

Comment: As on August, 2023, This is not the case. The free plan has only 10SMS/Day free. For Above it, you need to pay sms costs as per the rate listed here: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing#current-months-pricing Pricing seems very high compared to normal transactional sms providers

Answer (score -1):

https://firebase.google.com/pricing

$0.1/verification after the 10k monthly free tier.

Comment: It's $0.01/verification not $0.1 @Jason